# How to keep css content position when zooming in and out?

Tags: html, css

Every time i zoom in and out, in my browser, my content moves out of position. How do i keep my content in place when zooming in and out in the browser. I've been searching this topic but i can not find a solution to this problem.

```css
#top-container{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 105px;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    
                    
                }
                body{
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                #luxlogo{
                    width: 300px;
                    height: 105px;
                    margin-left: 700px;
                }
```

```html
 <div id="top-container">
                <img id="luxlogo" src="luxpics/luxlogo.png">
             </div>
```

Comment: Its a pretty broad description, can you show code or elaborate more clearly? What type of zoom, browser zoom or elementZoom... Are you referring to objectfit like shown here on a codepen demo > http://codepen.io/norcaljohnny/pen/oYvdpG

Comment: Sorry i added it. No when you physically press "CTRL + plus or minus" it makes your screen small. Look at the code i sent. When the picture is centered, when you zoom in and out it moves left and right.

Comment: For that you can use position: absolute and give it a top and left position or use background-position: cover or contain.

Comment: I may be understanding you wrong.. are you wanting for it to stay right? The reason being, it is doing what you are asking with the margin-left, so on zoom in or out it will move with the margin based on 700px

Comment: It didn't work. But when i insert the picture inside a div and fit it so it fits the div, it doesnt move :D it stays one place and just get smaller and bigger.

Comment: Maybe the position. So i guess if i put it inside a "div" it wont move then @norcaljohnny

Comment: correct that's what it will do with absolute positioning..follow and stay contained in the nearest relative div. Either way glad it worked out. :) Should I post it as an answer so it can be saved for future q and a?

Comment: Yes please go ahead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poster said this worked for the comment section so I am adding as an answer.

> For that you can use position: absolute and give it a top and left
>   position or use background-position: cover or contain.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the id #luxlogo

```
 #luxlogo{
width: 300px;
height: 105px;
position: absolute;
right:20px;
}
```