# Why does the logo move to the right when zoomed in? I want it to stay in the same position

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I try to zoom into the website, the logo moves and I want it to stay in place. I tried to ask ChatGPT about it but got no real good answers.

```
        .logo {
          width: 80px;
          height: 40px;
          background-image: url('clarekicon3.svg');
          background-size: contain;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-position: center;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          position: fixed;
          left: 10px;
          top: 41px; 
          
        }
        
        @media (min-width: 900px) {
          .logo {
            background-image: url('clarkelogo2.svg');
            margin-top: -38px;
            margin-left: 670px;
          }
        }
```

I originally tried changing the position from flex to absolute. Could anybody try to help me fix this?

Comment: Please provide a code that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Define the position of the logo as a function of the displayed screen size.

Answer (score 1):

With the styles you have written it is expected to move right as you zoom in and this behavior is because of the added margin. If you want the logo to be placed in the desired position maybe you can try `position: absolute`, give a `top`, `left` value, and remove your margins.

A similar question was answered already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392735/how-to-keep-css-content-position-when-zooming-in-and-out).